# FragmentTabHost with FloatingActionMenu Android

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, floating-action-button, fragment-tab-host

I am creating an Android layout with a `FragmentTabHost` and a `FloatingActionMenu` on the bottom right of the page. For some reason, the `onClickListener` that I attached to the menu is being called when I click anywhere on the whole page. I cannot figure out why this is happening, I'm pretty new to `RelativeLayout` so my lack of understanding its functionality might be the source of the issue.

Can anyone tell me why I might be seeing this behavior?

**MainActivity's `layout.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    tools:context=".Activities.LandingActivityPackage.LandingTabActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget

            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_account"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fab_size="mini"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_18dp"/>
            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fab_size="mini"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white_18dp"/>
        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

And this is how I attach the listener in the Java.

```
FloatingActionMenu fam = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.floating_action_menu);
fam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("fam clicked");
    }
});
```